# Autonne-Takagi factorization for complex symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singular-values

Let us consider a complex symmetric matrix $\Omega$. The Autonne-Takagi factorization tells us that a unitary matrx $U$ exists such that
$$U^T\Omega U = D,$$
where $D$ is a real diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries. I am trying to prove, from this expression, that $D$ is the square root of the diagonal form of the matrix $\Omega^\dagger\Omega$, diagonalized by the matrix $U$. In the specific, that 
$$
U^\dagger\Omega^\dagger\Omega U = D^2.$$
How can I derive the second expression from the first one? Although it seems pretty simple, I may be missing some obvious property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D^2=D^\ast D=(U^T\Omega U)^\ast (U^T\Omega U)=U^\ast\Omega^\ast\Omega U$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that $U^\dagger\Omega^\dagger (U^T)^\dagger U^T\Omega U= U^\dagger\Omega^\dagger (U^T)^\dagger U^T\Omega U=U^\dagger\Omega^\dagger (UU^\dagger)^T\Omega U=U^\dagger\Omega^\dagger \Omega U$